# Empirical Cumulative Density Function - R software

Tags: r, statistics, empirical-distribution

I have a problem with plotting ECDF. I try to reverse the x axis value like 1-(the function).
Because I wanna have smaller in the beginning of the graph and decreasing like in my reference graph.

```
load("91-20.RData")
ts <- data.frame(dat91,dat92,dat93,dat94,dat95,dat96,dat97,
                 dat98,dat99,dat00,dat11,dat12,dat12,dat13,
                 dat14,dat15,dat16,dat17,dat18,dat19,dat20)
ts
tsclean <- na.omit(ts)
#--------------------------------------------------------

ggplot(tsclean, aes(tsclean$dat91)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step")
```

This graph what i have, but i wanna duplicate like the reference
[image: output script]
[image: reference]

```
load("91-20.RData")
ts <- data.frame(dat91,dat92,dat93,dat94,dat95,dat96,dat97,
                 dat98,dat99,dat00,dat11,dat12,dat12,dat13,
                 dat14,dat15,dat16,dat17,dat18,dat19,dat20)
ts
tsclean <- na.omit(ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the graph you're looking for is called an "exceedance" graph. A web search finds some resources; try a web search for "R exceedance graph".

EDIT: This is more suitable as a comment than an answer, but my web browser is being unhelpful at the moment; sorry for the distraction.